# How to choose the Normalization method for a co-occurence matrix?

Tags: categorical-data, normalization, matrix, z-score, euclidean

I have a co-occurrence matrix about hashtags usage (The value in the cell means the number of times two hashtags appear together in a single tweet), it is transformed from a 2-mode matrix. Now I want to use `Ucinet` to normalize this matrix because I have 4 matrices like this in different periods. Indeed, I want to compare the usage of hashtags at different times, so I should normalize all 4 matrices to decrease dimensional effects.

But I find that `ucinet` offers different methods for that: z-scores, marginal, Euclidean and so on. Which is the best? I don't know how to choose and I also find there is some difference between outcomes by different methods. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to make sure I understood correctly, (1) you have four $n \times n$ frequency tables. (2) you want to be able to compare these tables. Is that right? $n$ is the number of hashtags.

Comment: @utobi Hi, thank u for your reply! yes, I have 4 tables, but each one does not contain the same hashtags. The first one contains 100X100, the second for 120X120, the third 130X130, last 145X145. Some of them are repetitive and some of them are specific. I want to normalize these matrices and just compare  10 hashtags specifically.

Comment: For the tables to be comparable you have to wash out the sample size effect. To do this you simply divide each cell by the grand total. In this way, the resulting cells will be numbers between 0 and 1 and are thus comparable across different tables, i.e. tables from different time points, or experimental conditions, etc.

Comment: @utobi Thank you! It is so clear. And in ucinet there are 3 method of normalization: (1) Euclidean - Forces the Euclidean norm,  to be one; (2) Maximum - Forces the maximum of the elements to be 100; (3) Z-Score - Forces the mean of the elements to be zero and the standard deviation to be 1.  By row, column, matrix or row and column.  If standard deviation is initially zero then elements of matrix are treated as missing.    Is it OK for me to use either one? or only the "Maximum"

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with `ucinet`, but maybe I am missing something from your problem. Could you share and describe one of these tables in your post?  It is not clear to me if you have a table for each tweet or if you pull the tables across many tweets. If you consider a table for a single tweet, I guess the tables would be very sparse.

Comment: @utobi Sure, this is one of my co-occurence matrix(partly). 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyoff.png    The value in the cell means the number of times tag A and tag B appear together in the tweet( I have hundreds of thousands of tweets, and each tweet is analyzed as a co-occurrence unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the co-occurrence table is a quadratic and symmetric matrix around the main diagonal, it doesn't make any difference if you read it by rows or by columns. The main diagonal seems to be zero everywhere, which makes sense since it's unlikely that one repeats the same hashtag within the same tweet.

My suggestion is to normalize row-wise (or column-wise), that is, to divide each row by its total. In this way, the $i$th row of the table would represent the relative frequency distribution of co-occurrences for the hashtag $i$. You can now compare this frequency distribution with other frequency distributions from other tables or for other tags.

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to compute quantiles or moment-based summaries on these distributions (so z-score is not meaningful either) since the variable in question is qualitative, i.g. having modalities "#1 vs #1", ..., "#1 vs #n".

You can instead use use the mode (i.e. the co-occurence with highest relative frequency) as a measure of location. As a measure of "variability" or entropy you may use the Shannon entropy.

If we denote by $p_{j|i}$ be the relative frequency of the co-occurence "#i vs #j", for $j = 1,\ldots,k$, the Shannon entropy is

$$
H = \sum_{j=1}^k p_{i|j}\log p_{j|i},
$$

with $p_{j|i}\log p_{j|i} = 0$ if $p_{j|i}=0$. $H$ assumes value zero, i.e. its minimum, when the distribution is uniform. Furthermore, it can be shown that $H\leq \log k$, thus if you use $H$ to compare frequency distributions with different $k$'s, it's better to use its normalized version
$$
H_n = \frac{H}{\log(k)}.
$$

Comment: It is so clear! Thank you for your help and time, I will try to use the Shannon entropy method, thanks again!